# Loop not doing its job

Tags: c++

Newbie here. Don't be surprised if it's a simple problem.

Here is this snippet of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

char a;

int c = 0;

void mva()
{
    std::cout << "Nothing here yet, move along." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Press \"e\" to exit or \"r\" to return" << std::endl;
}

void cho()
{
    std::cout << "Choose a valid option noob!" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Press \"e\" to exit or \"r\" to return" << std::endl;
}

void menu()
{
    std::cout << "Welcome." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Choose an option" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "1." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "2. " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "3." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "4." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "5." << std::endl; //5 is exit
}
int main()
{
    menu();
    std::cin >> c;
    switch (c)
    {
    case 1:
        mva();
        std::cin >> a;
        while (a != 'e' || a != 'r')
        {
            switch (a)
            {
                 case 'e':
                     exit(0);
                     break;

                 case 'r':
                     break;

                 default:
                     cho();
                     std::cin >> a;
                     break;
            }
        }
        break;
    case 5:
        exit(0);
        break;
    default:
        cho();
        std::cin >> a;
        while (a != 'e' || a != 'r') {
            switch (a)
            {
            case 'e':
                exit(0);
                break;

            case 'r':
                break;

            default:
                cho();
                std::cin >> a;
                break;
            }

        }
        break;
    }
return 0;
}
```

It has the user choose from 5 options. When an option is finished (just printing text for now), the user is supposed to choose 'e' (to exit; this DOES work) or 'r' to return to the menu (which would just print the options and take the user input again). However, pressing 'r' and then enter doesn't print the options again and ask the user for input; it does... nothing? I have no idea how to do this. I suspect I need to implement `menu()` somewhere, but I don't know where. This problem has been very confusing and I'd appreciate help.

Comment: Expecting some effort from you. Go through C++ basics.

Comment: @JithinPavithran I've rethought the whole thing and I've realized the whole choose a character thing is unnecessary. However, I've found a solution anyway; have a look: https://pastebin.com/LbuZwTK6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition should be

```
while (a != 'e' && a != 'r')
```

Otherwise it is always `true` no matter what value of `a` you enter.

Comment: Alright, that's better, thanks. However, when I type 'r' it just exits. What can I do for that?

Comment: Fix the logic under `case 'r'`

Comment: How, exactly? How am I supposed to make it return to the menu and ask for user input?

Comment: more specifically, I want it to break and loop back to the choice menu.

Comment: Instead of a bunch of functions that take no arguments are don't return anything (`void`) you should refactor your code. Have functions return variables (e.g. `std::string`, `bool`, as appropriate), then you pass things in and out of functions. It is better to do flow control in this way rather than a bunch of carefully nested loops with `break`s

Comment: I've rethought the whole thing and I've realized the whole choose a character thing is unnecessary. However, I've found a solution anyway; have a look: pastebin.com/LbuZwTK6